# Android layout - image pushes view away

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, imageview

This is my layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottleImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_food_milk" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/diaperImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_store_diaper" />

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/glview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:windowIsTranslucent="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In application onCreate I hide both imageviews and then when necessary I show them. But when I do that, GLSurfaceView moves to the right for the width of the imageview.

Comment: try this :.... android:layout_gravity="bottom | left"

Comment: coz your Parent android:orientation="horizontal" change it to vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, you are using `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation. When you make your imageViews visible, all your views from this viewGroup will try to fit horizontally. In this case if you want to make the position fix, use `RelativeLayout` with `alignParentBottom = true`

Answer (score 0):

your Parent layout is linear layout its orientation is

```
 android:orientation="horizontal"
```

this will always be in horizontal position

```
|    |  
view1 view2....
|    |
```

change that to `android:orientation="vertical"

then your view should be

```
view 1
view 2
.
.
```

Comment: If I change it to "vertical" then GLSurfaceView moves down instead of left.